# Adding elements to a Map after checking condition scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a case class

```
case class DDD(abc: String, v1: String, v2: String)
```

and i have a tuple based on the DDD (schema). So imagine this

```
val sample1 = DDD("a1", "v0001", "v0002")
```

and then i am making a Map out of this tuple values like this

```
val tMap = Map("col_name" -> sample1.abc, "col_old" -> sample1.v1, "col_new" -> sample1.v2)
```

But there might be some cases where my v1 or v2 values in my tuples might be blank/null/empty  and if the value is not present i don't want to add that key-value pair to my map so 
**For Example**

```
If 
val sample2 = DDD("a1", "null", "v0002")

Then
val tMap = Map("col_name" -> sample1.abc, "col_new" -> sample1.v2)
```

I am able to achieve this simply by using if condition like below

```
val sample2 = DDD("a1", "null", "v0002")

val tMap = Map("col_old" -> (if(sample2.v1 != "null") sample2.v1),
"col_new" -> (if(sample2.v2 != "null") sample2.v2
"abc" -> (if(sample2.abc != "null") sample2.abc
)
```

But need to do & understand how can i achieve it in a cleaner functional way. ???

Thanks

Comment: Hint: you can define case class object DDD, here you write you define your auxiliary constructors based on your specific conditions

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this.

```
case class DDD(abc: String, v1: String, v2: String)

val sample1 = DDD("a1", "null", "v0002")

val mapKeys = List("col_name", "col_old", "col_new")

val tMap =
  (mapKeys.toIterator zip sample1.productIterator).collect {
    case (k, v: String) if (v != "null")=> k -> v
  }.toMap
// tMap: Map[String, String] = Map(col_name -> a1, col_new -> v0002)
```

Comment: don't want to set mapKeys separately

Comment: @AJm What is the problem with having the keys as an outer list?

Comment: We have certain code standards to follow this won't be accepted

Comment: @AJm What code standard would disallow this? For what specific reason? - Also, if you can not have the keys as any kind of collection, there would not be any other solution as checking the condition and adding the values one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you create a custom unapply method for that case class?

By default Scala create a singleton object where the apply and unapply method are specified. So you should create another one.

```
object DDD {
   def unapply(arg: DDD): Map[String, String] = {
      def mapIfNotNull(key:String, value:String):Option[(String, String)] = if (value == "null") None else Some(key -> value)
      Seq(
        mapIfNotNull("col_name", arg.abc),
        mapIfNotNull("col_old", arg.v1),
        mapIfNotNull("col_new", arg.v2)
      ).flatten.toMap
    } 
}
```

Then you can use this singleton later to unapply the case class instance.

```
DDD.unapply(sample1)
```

I think this way is more cleaner